# SQL for delete query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to write an SQL query for my program, but I just can't figure out how. I don't know enough SQL.

I'm trying to implement an online team system (for some website). I have two tables:

```
teams | teamId, eventId
teammembers | teamId, userId, status
```

Now, I need to: delete all records in `teammembers` where the eventId for the corresponding `teamId` is 1.

I'm trying:

```
delete from teammembers where teamId=teams.teamId and teams.eventId=1;
```

I'm not sure if this is really doing what I'm trying to do.

Is this query wrong, and if it is (which probably is), how can I write such a query?

Comment: Give this a try: `delete from teammembers where teamId in (select teamId from teams where eventId = 1)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't specify your RDBMS so here it is in MySQL

```
DELETE teammembers FROM teammembers
JOIN teams on teammembers.teamId = teams.teamId
WHERE teams.eventId = 1
```

Comment: +1 for not using unneeded subselects. However dont you need to speify you only want to delete the `teammembers` records and not the `teams` records as well when you do a join in a delete statement?

Comment: and can you explain why this query is more efficient than using subselects? or point me to a link that does that? I don't want to have ask stuff on SO each time I face a tough query situation :)

Comment: with the sub-query it has to store all the results of the sub-query before it can perform / finish the outer part.  This takes more resources.  Also, all sql systems are very good at doing joins so they often work better because the engine was designed to do them fast.

Comment: @jrharshath: MySQL is notoriously terrible at subquery optimization. In many cases, for every row of the outer query, it executes the inner query.

Comment: @jrharshath: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Comment: Also: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/ I suggest googling for mysql and subquery.

Comment: @hobodave: it would not do it for every row using in as part of the where clause.

Comment: @hobodave: too true, can't count the number of times I've seen it written by beginning programmers.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I would do in SQL Server

```
DELETE tm 
--select tm.*
FROM teammembers tm
JOIN teams t on tm.teamId = t.teamId 
WHERE t.eventId = 1
```

By embedding a select in the comment, I can run just this part manually and see what records I'm going to affect before I run the delete while I'm in development.

```
select tm.*
FROM teammembers tm
JOIN teams t on tm.teamId = t.teamId 
WHERE t.eventId = 1
```

I never run a delete statment for the first time without checking to see that the records I think I'm going to delete are the records I intended to delete. This check will save you lots of worry as to whether your more complex deletes are affecting only the records you want to affect.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a sub-query or a join, I think join is faster.

```
delete from teammembers
join teams on teammembers.teamid = teams.teamid
where teams.eventid = 1
```

Comment: np @hobodave, I don't mind them at all when I learn something new.

Comment: Hogan: I didn't downvote your answer but your query is wrong. It will delete rows in the teams table too.

Comment: @Mark - I saw that on hobodaves comments and answers.  I think that is mysql only as this will work fine on mssql.  Anyone know what the standard is?

Comment: He didn't tag it as mysql, but he said in a comment that he is using mysql.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [multi-table delete syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE teammembers
FROM teammembers
JOIN teams ON teamId=teams.teamId 
WHERE teams.eventId=1;
```

(I'm assuming MySQL here)

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from teammembers where teamid in 
(
  select teamid from teams where eventid = 1
)
```

Assuming that teamid is the joining column.

Comment: why use a non-scalable where IN instead of a join?

Comment: a join should be faster (and better solution IMHO)

Comment: @hobodave: yes, that would be an issue for mysql, but not necessarily for other DBs (depending on the metrics etc.)

Comment: @davek: this performs worse on mssql too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
delete from teammembers where teamId in (select teamId from teams where eventId=1);
```

Edit: As some comments already suggest, the more efficient way is indeed through a join:

```
delete from teammebers
join teams on teams.teamId = teammembers.teamId
where eventId = 1
```